# Error while Installing Tomcat6 on Linux Debian Squeeze

Tags: linux, tomcat6

I install Tomcat6 and try to run the server but its not starting up. I checked the log and found out this error.

```
Apr 29, 2014 3:29:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base /usr/share/tomcat6-examples/examples does not exist or is not a readable directory
```

Then I have checked and the directory `/usr/share/tomcat6-examples/examples` exist.

Is there anything else I am missing? Thanks!

Comment: The message states `does not exist or is not a readable directory`. Did you check the permissions? Whatever user Tomcat is running as needs to be able to dive down into this dir and read it.

Comment: @SvW Yes, even I tried to give all the permission to every one for the directory "tomcat6-examples" but still I am getting the same error.